# Ruby on Rails undefined local variable or method in console

Tags: ruby, module, irb, article

**What is problem? I don't understand.**

[image]

Comment: I guess what you try to do is `Article.all`, not `article.all` - case matters.

Comment: Please, post text as text, not as photographs of text. This is a website for programmers, not photographers. We want to copy&paste&run your code, copy&paste your inputs, read your outputs, and copy&paste&google your error messages, not critique your use of color and perspective. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2988 https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things that could be happening. First, you meant to list Article.all, referencing the class. Second, you're referencing article.all as a array, in which case it hasn't been defined as such in your code.

Also, please don't post images of code. Just copy/paste and use the code formatting tools. It really helps us understand what is going on.

Also, it helps to give as much background as possible, meaning what the code is supposed to do, why you're doing it, etc. The more thorough you are, the more helpful we can be.